# Getting unknown Segmentation Fault "(address) in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,..., std::allocator<char> > const&) const ()

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm making a program in c++ that represents a forum which has those classes and structs:

```
struct Date{            /* struct used to get a random day for each comment */
    int d,m,y,h,min;
    Date();
    void GetDate() const;
};

class Post{
  private:
    std::string Title;
    std::string Creator;
    std::string text;
    Date PostDate;
    int id;
  public:
    Post();
    ~Post();
    void postprint() const;
    int idprint();
    std::string get_creator() const; //returns the creator of the post
};

class Thread{
  private:
    std::string Subject;
    std::string Creator;
    Date ThreadDate;
    int post_nums = rand()%10+1;   // this will be the number of posts that will be made in the thread, used in threadprint()
    Post *posts = new Post[post_nums]; //so the randomizer doesn't return 0 array cells, max 10 posts for each thread
  public:
    Thread();
    ~Thread();
    std::string subjprint() const;
    void threadprint() const;
    int getnums() const; //returns the number of posts in the posts array
    Post *getposts() const; //returns to a pointer the array of posts
};

class Forum{
  private:
    std::string Title;
    Thread *threads = new Thread[3];
    //void printt(int) const;
  public:
    Forum(const std::string);
    ~Forum();
    void Print_threads() const;
    void Print_specified_thread(const std::string);
    Thread *Find_thread_subject(const std::string);
    void Print_specified_post(const int);
    Post *Find_specified_post(const int);
};

struct Post_list{
  Post *post;
  Post_list *next;
  Post_list *prev;
};

struct Tree_node{
  std::string Creator;
  Post_list *list_ptr;
  Tree_node *left;
  Tree_node *right;
};

class Thread_tree{
  private:
    Tree_node *node_root;
    void Tree_create(Tree_node *);
    int Tree_empty(Tree_node *);
    void Tree_sort(const Thread *, Tree_node *);
    void Tree_insert(const std::string, Tree_node *);
  public:
    Thread_tree(const Thread *);
};
```

Now I am trying to put the creators of the comments of each Thread into a BST, sorting them out, where each node `struct Tree_node` has a creator string and his comments on a list.The constructor of `class Thread_tree` is something like this

```
Thread_tree::Thread_tree(const Thread *Thread1){  //constructor only to be called once
  cout << "Creating tree of post creators from thread " << Thread1->subjprint() << endl;
  Tree_create(this->node_root); //points root to NULL
  Tree_sort(Thread1, this->node_root);
}
```

while `Tree_sort()` is

```
void Thread_tree::Tree_sort(const Thread *Thread1, Tree_node *root){
  int k = Thread1->getnums(); //k is assigned to the number of the posts that the thread has
  Post *post_ptr = Thread1->getposts(); //ptr is assigned to the posts array of the thread
  for (int i=0; i<k; i++){
    cout << "\ni is " << i << endl;
    Tree_insert((post_ptr+i)->get_creator(), root);
  }
}
```

and `Tree_insert()`

```
void Thread_tree::Tree_insert(const string creator, Tree_node *root){
  if (Tree_empty(root)){
    root = new Tree_node;
    root->Creator = creator;
    root->list_ptr = NULL;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
  }
  else if (creator.compare(root->Creator) < 0){ //creator in string1 is smaller than the root->Creator
        Tree_insert(creator, (root->left));    // in ascending order

      }
   if (creator.compare(root->Creator) > 0) {//creator in string1 is bigger than the root->Creator
        Tree_insert(creator, (root->right));   //in ascending order
      }
}
```

In main() when I make a tree `Thread_tree Tree1(thread);` with 'thread' being a pointer pointing to an existing thread, I get a segmentation fault. I run the gdb debugger and after using `bt` I get this message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b7625a in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b7625a in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00000000004025f1 in Thread_tree::Tree_insert (this=0x7fffffffe7c0, creator="user1234", root=0x1002) at classes.cpp:211
#2  0x00000000004026be in Thread_tree::Tree_insert (this=0x7fffffffe7c0, creator="user1234", root=0x604110) at classes.cpp:218
#3  0x00000000004024e4 in Thread_tree::Tree_sort (this=0x7fffffffe7c0, Thread1=0x616d98, root=0x604110) at classes.cpp:197
#4  0x00000000004023b7 in Thread_tree::Thread_tree (this=0x7fffffffe7c0, Thread1=0x616d98) at classes.cpp:181
#5  0x0000000000402f03 in main () at main.cpp:19
```

I can't understand what the problem is, as from what I understand from the message, the program crushes at the second call of `Tree_insert()`

Comment: `root=0x1002` That's a suspicious pointer value, especially considering that the rest of your heap-allocated pointers are above 0x600000... Are you leaving something uninitialised, such as the `.left` or `.right` members of `Tree_node` (try defaulting those to `nullptr` in the struct definition)?

Comment: How `Tree_create` is implemented? It looks like it doesn't just set `this->root` to `NULL`.

Comment: @Stu I did that as well and I am getting the same error

Comment: @Rhathin `Tree_create` 's body is this `root = NULL;`

Comment: I've also noticed that `Tree_empty` returns `int`. How do you check this "emptiness"?

Comment: @Rhathin `Tree_empty` basically returns this: `return (root == NULL);`, so in the if condition in `Tree_insert` 's body  `if (Tree_empty(root))` , if root does indeed point to NULL a new `Tree_node` will be made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `Tree_create(this->node_root);`

`Tree_create` creates copy of pointer passed to it and assigns `NULL` to this copy, while `this->node_root` stays unchanged and is uninitialized when `Tree_sort` is called.

Simplest solution is to assign `NULL` (or `nullptr` which is preferable in `c++11`) directly to `this->node_root`

The same applies to your other methods. When you pass pointer by value, any assignment to it is done on copy. Solution here is to pass pointers by reference (e.g. `Tree_create(Tree_node*& root)`)

Comment: Okay so you are saying I should also change the argument `const Thread *Thread1` of ``Tree_sort`` and the constructor `Thread_tree` to `const Thread*& Thread1` ?

Comment: @stefnto You don't modify `Thread1` pointer, so it's ok to pass it by value. Pass pointer by reference only if you need to assign new address to it.

Comment: Your answer fixed my problem, but I'm still getting a segmentation fault later on, can I ask you here about it or should I make a new question?

Comment: @stefnto It's better to ask new question, to avoid making this one too broad.